# What will happen if we interchange @service and @repository annotation in the spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Why we needs to use `@service` inside the service Implementation and `@repository` in the DAO Implementation. There are no problem occur when I interchange the `@service` and `@repository` annotation in the spring MVC.

Comment: That would probably screw up your transactions. A service needs to pass transactions that need propagation to the DAO. Both are components so creation of a bean wont be a problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [documentaion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-stereotype-annotations) `@Repository`,`@Service`,`@Controller` are all synonyms. They all are just specializations of `@Component` annotation. So, generally, they can be used one instead of other. But ... you should not do this.

First reason: any of these annotations *make clear the role* of your component in the application. Shows - is this component belongs to the controller, service, or data layer.

Second reason: some of these annotations processed differently by different Spring modules. For example, `Spring Data JPA` will process `@Repository` and will try to replace with implementation any interface marked by this annotation. Spring also will apply automatic exception translation to such classes. Another example: `Spring Web MVC` processes `@Controller`, and uses classes marked with it in URL mappings.

Actually, in future versions, some modules of Spring could process `@Service` in a particular way. Not as simple `@Component`. That's why documentation advises:

> It is also possible that @Repository, @Service, and @Controller may
> carry additional semantics in future releases of the Spring Framework.
> Thus, if you are choosing between using @Component or @Service for
> your service layer, @Service is clearly the better choice.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you use for the remainder of the framework. In theory nothing changes as the `@Service` and `@Repository` annotations are basically `@Component` annotations. The same could be said for `@Controller` or `@Endpoint` (for Spring Ws and there are more).

However they express an intent of what a class is (a service, a repository) and makes it clear to the user to what layer that class belongs.

However if you also use Spring for transaction managemnt then `@Repository` is also a trigger for [adding exception translation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java) to that class (also see the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/dao.html#dao-annotations)).

Although nothing *has* to break it probably will at some point.

Answer (score 0):

**According to documentation**

Service.java

> ```
> @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
> @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
> @Documented
> @Component
> public @interface Service {
>   @AliasFor(annotation = Component.class)
>   String value() default "";
> }
> ```

Repository.java

> ```
> @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
> @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
> @Documented
> @Component
> public @interface Repository {
>   @AliasFor(annotation = Component.class)
>   String value() default "";
> }
> ```

So after reading documentation, it seems we don't get immediate error and theoretically is possible but it is not good practice.If in future Spring offically add new line of code then we may get error.